# BigDecimal in Java: How to round to 10?

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

I want to round BigDecimal numbers to 10 up or down:

112 --> 110

117 --> 120

150 --> 150

115 --> 120

114.9 --> 110

67 --> 70

64 --> 60

etc.

I tried this:

`number = number.round(new MathContext(1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));`

11 —> 10

150 —> 200 // wrong! should be 150!

48 —> 50

500 —> 500

250 —> 300 // wrong! should be 250!

240 —> 200 // wrong! should be 240!

245 —> 200 // wrong! should be 250!

51 -> 50

I have tried several other values for precision, but I never get correct rounding for all values.

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing that the `MathContext` object with which you are performing the rounding specifies the *precision* of the rounded result (== number of significant digits), not the scale (related to the place value of the least-significant digit). More generally, `BigDecimal.round()` is all about managing the precision of your numbers, which is not what you're after.

You can round a `BigDecimal` to the nearest multiple of any given power of 10 by setting its *scale*.  To round to the nearest multiple of 10 itself, that would be:

```
number = number.setScale(-1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
```

Note that if the initial scale is less than -1, then this results in an *increase* in the precision of the number (by addition of significant trailing zeroes).  If you don't want that, then test the scale (`BigSecimal.scale()`) to determine whether to round.

Comment: Great explanation. `BigDecimal.round()` is misleading. Tx

Comment: but this returns things like 21 -> 20E+10 rather than a rounded BigDecimal

Comment: @AnnaT.  If you run `BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal("21"); number = number.setScale(-1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); System.out.println(number.toString());`, the output is `2E+1`, which shows that the rescaled `BigDecimal` represents the number 20, with only one significant digit.  Do not confuse this string representation with the `BigDecimal` itself.  You can, of course add *significant* trailing zeroes, which will be presented in string values, by setting the scale of the result to a larger number.  Or if you use, say, `intValue()` then you will get 20 as an `int`.

Comment: Note also that from a perspective of maintaining the correct number of significant digits, reducing the scale is exactly the right way to round.  Rounding *should* reduce the number of significant digits.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
private BigDecimal round(BigDecimal value) {
    value = value.multiply(new BigDecimal(0.01));
    value = value.setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    value = value.multiply(new BigDecimal(100));
    return value;
}
```

But the correct way to perform the scale is:

```
value = value.setScale(-1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Here you will have the exponential representation of the number.
You can use this method:

```
value.toPlainString();
```

to get back the plain string.

> toPlainString() Returns a string
>   representation of this BigDecimal without an exponent field.

Comment: Well ok, but it's wasteful to do the pre- and post-multiplication.  It just changes which is the appropriate scale to pass to `setScale()`.

Comment: Yes, if the scale is less than zero then the default `String` representation uses exponential notation.  This is the only way to avoid displaying non-significant digits, as the units digit is not significant in that case.  Depending on the purpose of rounding, it might be suitable to increase the precision by setting the scale of the result to 0.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to do with an ordinary `int`:

Math.round(number/10f)*10

Assuming `number` is 42, `number/10f` is 4.2, which rounds to `4.0`, which when multiplied by 10 give 40.

Comment: But when what I got is a BigDecimal, this is not helping me.